# Can G++ coexist side by side with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I have Visual Studio 2013 Community installed. Now want to learn more about compiling, as well as being more Windows independent/portable, with Notepad/G++11/MinGW-64 (all within same Windows 10 Home 64bit platform for c++ audio applications). Can GCC and VS coexist side by side?

Comment: Yes, as long as they are in different directories, they don't affect each other.

Comment: You can even have multiple installations of Visual Studio (2013, 2015, 2019, 2022, etc), as long as they reside in their own directories.

Comment: Thx Bop and PaulMcKenzie for delayless reply. Feeling already better and can now proceed forward!

Comment: TLDR: yes they can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can, of course, have both installed side-by-side. But you cannot expect to be able to link object files / libraries compiled by different compilers (or even different compiler versions) in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Carl. You can have these two compilers installed and co-exist in Win10x64. Just like Jesper sais, be certain to rebuild all libraries and app modules (with either one of these compiles) you plan to use, as it is far from recommended to mix binaries (compiled modules) comming from different compilers (especially with c++ as opposed to c, where it is possible but not recommended neither)